# Custom lookup function in R not working within dplyr::mutate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, custom-function

I'm trying to use a custom function, which filters a dataframe and pulls information from another column, within `dplyr::mutate` with `dplyr version 0.8.3`. I'm getting two types of errors. One with a large dataframe yields `Error: Result must have length 32, not 1728` as an error and the other, used in the following example code, does not return an error message but returns a wrong match.

**Lookup Dataframe**

```
lookup.df<-data.frame(to.match=paste(letters[1:7],letters[8:14],sep = ""),
                       match=c("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven"))

lookup.df

  to.match match
1       ah   one
2       bi   two
3       cj three
4       dk  four
5       el  five
6       fm   six
7       gn seven
```

**Lookup Fucntion**

```
lookup_function<-function(x){
  y<-lookup.df %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
    filter(to.match==x) %>% 
    pull(match)
  y
}

Vectorize(lookup_function)
```

**Terminal Run**

Running the function from the terminal does return the expected results.

```
> lookup_function("dk")
[1] "four"
> lookup_function("el")
[1] "five"
```

**dplyr::mutate Run**

Running the same function to a diffrent dataframe within dplyr::mutate does not return the expected results.

```
 live.df<-data.frame(to.match=rev(paste(letters[1:7],letters[8:14],sep = "")))

 live.df %>% 
   mutate(live.match=lookup_function(to.match))

  to.match live.match
1       gn       four
2       fm       four
3       el       four
4       dk       four
5       cj       four
6       bi       four
7       ah       four
```

The code should, *in this example at least*, should return the match column of the lookup.df but reversed but it instead returns `four` in every row.

**Vector through Sapply**

The function does seem to return the appropriate results when piped through `sapply`.

```
c("dk","el") %>% sapply(lookup_function)
    dk     el 
"four" "five"
```

I'm barely familiarized with Vectorization of cutom functions for this type of use so I'm unsure if that is the source of this error.

What would be the propper way to fix this custom function so that it returns the correct information from the lookup dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the use of OP's function with `Vectorize`, the function would be either updated as `lookup_function <- Vectorize(lookup_function)` and then apply the code as in OP's post or do this on the fly

```
library(dplyr)
live.df %>% 
     mutate(live.match=Vectorize(lookup_function)(to.match))
#  to.match live.match
#1       gn      seven
#2       fm        six
#3       el       five
#4       dk       four
#5       cj      three
#6       bi        two
#7       ah        one
```

But, it would be inefficient as it does filter for each match (`filter(to.match==x)` ), which is inefficient

---

We can use a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
live.df %>%
     left_join(lookup.df)
```

---

Or use `match`

```
live.df %>%
      mutate(match = lookup.df$match[match(to.match, lookup.df$to.match)])
```

which can be also used in `base R`

```
live.df$match <- with(live.df, lookup.df$match[match(to.match, lookup.df$to.match)])
```

Comment: I was able to make use of the `left_join` solution for my code. The Vectorized custom function also worked in the sample code, I was missing the assignment operator in that case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IsraelGirón-Palacios  Here, the `Vectorize` is doing a `lapply` which is again a loop

Comment: Part of the intent was avoding merging as there are other dataframes in this project that wont have a hard set join condition so they ended up generating additional rows of data that was faulty. Using the `left_join` solution you proposed I just filtered out the rows that were faulty. So far I haven't come accross one that would require anything other than `left_join` and `filter` to do the lookup that was originally intended. I do belive that I will have one that will need `grepl` to find a pattern in a string but there may be another work around for that one.

Comment: @IsraelGirón-Palacios `match` would be fast enough and if the strings are not completely matching, use `grepl`